# GWT CheckBox. Extra data in onClick(ClickEvent event)

Tags: gwt, checkbox, onclick

I have got the table and would like to have some info about a clicked row in the `onClick(ClickEvent event)` method. E.g., If I click the `CheckBox` in the header row, all other `CheckBox`es should automatically be checked (something like "Select all"). After clicking some other `CheckBox`, I would like to have the ID of the appropriate row. How can I do it?

[image: Screenshot]

**SOLVED.**

```
CheckBox selectCb = new CheckBox();
selectCb.addClickHandler(this);
selectCb.getElement().setId(CheckBoxIds.SELECT_ALL);

@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // OK, an "instanceof Widget" would intercept the if condition below
    if (event.getSource() instanceof CheckBox) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
        String elementId = checkBox.getElement().getId();
        if (elementId.equals(CheckBoxIds.SELECT_ALL)) {
            boolean checked = checkBox.getValue();
            LOGGER.info("Checked: " + checked);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit #1.**

Various `ClickHandler`s for the header check box, other check boxes, buttons and so on.

```
/**
 * The {@link ClickHandler} for the header row
 */
private ClickHandler mHeaderCbClickHandler = new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
        boolean checked = checkBox.getValue();
        for (int row = NO_DATA_HEADER_ROWS_COUNT; row < mFlexTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
            CheckBox dataCb = (CheckBox) mFlexTable.getWidget(row, MockDataProvider.CHECK_COLUMN_INDEX);
            dataCb.setValue(checked);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * The {@link ClickHandler} for a row with data
 */
private ClickHandler mRowCbClickHandler = new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

    }
};

/**
 * The {@link ClickHandler} for {@link Button}s
 */
private ClickHandler mButtonClickHandler = new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

// Use
CheckBox selectCb = new CheckBox();
selectCb.addClickHandler(mHeaderCbClickHandler);
// selectCb.getElement().setId(CheckBoxIds.SELECT_ALL); Not necessary now
```

Comment: @AndreaBoscolo, `FlexTable`. I have an idea but I am not sure that it's good. `checkBox.getElement().setId("UNIQUE_ID")` when creating a `CheckBox` and `checkBox.getElement().getId()` in `onClick()`

Comment: @AndreaBoscolo, it works! The code is above

Comment: Sure, but why not having different header/rows checkbox handlers in the first place? It's easier for this use case.